# XCode Developer Documentation crashes after clicking any link on the startup screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, crash

I just installed XCode 3.2.1.  When I open the Developer Documentation and click any link on the startup screen, XCode crashes.  Has anyone run into this problem?  Also hints as to how to debug would be excellent -- I've only been using XCode for a week.

I can still get into the documentation if I open some code and then right-click a symbol and choose "Find in Documentation."  But its annoying that I can't just open the docs and browse them.

I guess the answer is to reinstall?  I didn't really want to sit through a long install again, since I can still access the docs (just a pain to do so).  Once I get around to reinstalling, I will post the result back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this behavior (ie, "works for me"). Have you tried reinstalling Xcode Tools?

Comment: Yep, sadly the answer was "reinstall XCode and everything will work again."  Later I came to realize that "reinstall XCode" is the answer to many annoying little things that can happen while doing iOS development.  Sort of reminds me of an operating system made by some company in Redmond...